# Installing wordpress in sub-directory with .htaccess in root directory

Tags: .htaccess

So I have a .htaccess at the root directory of **example.com**:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(png|gif|ico|swf|jpe?g|js|css)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php?sef_rewrite=1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Now I'm installing wordpress at **example.com/blog/**, but after uploading wordpress files there, it's Page Not Found **404 error** when I visit http://www.example.com/blog/

My take is I should modify the .htaccess in the root directory of example.com or the request is redirected to /index.php rather than /blog/index.php

This is the line I added into the .htaccess in the root directory:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog
```

So the whole thing looks like:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(png|gif|ico|swf|jpe?g|js|css)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php?sef_rewrite=1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

But it doesn't work. It's still 404 error at example.com/blog/. I thought it should be something like that, right?

Then how should I modify the .htaccess in the root directory to make this work? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to put the htaccess in the root directory rather than the /blog/ directory?

Comment: Because I'm using cs-cart (a shopping cart software by cs-cart.com) at the root directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out it's a permissions thing that I didn't set up right in Linux. Not a .htaccess problem. So this question is meaningless.